# Microsoft Word Opens Previous Document Before Crashing

Tags: microsoft-word

I recently installed Office 365 Pro on my home computer and noticed Word was a bit funny. Excel works fine, but when I first opened up Word it showed a blank document, froze and closed down.

I opened a word file created on a different computer, and opened a new file from there and proceeded to write my new document. Word crashed on saving, and I ended up closing it via Task Manager. Now whenever I try to open a new or existing word document, my previous word document opens, Word freezes and then closes after a few seconds.

I have:

1. Used the Office repair tool and ran the online repair.
2. Completely uninstalled and reinstalled Office 365.
3. Located the temporary files and recovery files and deleted them for Word.

None of these three solutions worked for me. Has anyone else had a similar experience with Microsoft Word, and know how to repair it. When starting Word in safe mode, and opening Word while pressing the shift key I get the same issue as described.

Please see below a screenshot of my screen prior to Word crashing.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX4Tt.png)

Comment: "Completely uninstalled and reinstalled Office 365." - When you did this did you use the [Office uninstallation tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8)?

Comment: Hi @Ramhound. I did yes, and also did it from the Apps & Features menu

Comment: Try running Word in safe mode: `winword /safe` as a run command

Comment: @Ramhound that works, I can open a blank document and save it, but when opening word normally afterwards it still closes after a number of seconds. That's if I open a previously saved file or a new blank document.

Comment: What add-ons do you have installed? Is this machine connected to an AD domain by chance?

Comment: Only whatever came with the base program. I've not installed or enabled any. There are no Active Application Add-ins, and the Inactive Application Add-ins are 1. "ActionsPane Schema for Add-Ins". 2. "Microsoft Actions Pane 3". 3. "OneNote Notes about Word Documents". It's a personal computer, but I have got the MS Office licence through my work, so for Office I sign in with my work credentials for the licence.